# firefox addons, save data in simple-storage

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a Firefox addon, using Firefox Addon Builder.

I can't figure our how exactly I can save data in "simple-storage".

`main.js`:

```js
var data = require("self").data;

var ss = require("simple-storage");
if(typeof(ss.storage.bl) === 'undefined') {
  ss.storage.bl = [];
}
blacklist = ss.storage.bl;

exports.main = function(){
    var pageMod = require("page-mod");
    pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "*",
        contentScriptWhen: 'end',
        contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.min.js")] 
    });

    var contextmenu = require("context-menu");
    contextmenu.Item({
        label: "block",
        context: contextmenu.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
        contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.min.js"),data.url("onclick.js"),data.url("core.js")]     
    }); 
};
```

`onclick.js`:

```js
self.on("click", function (node) {
    user = node.href.substring(node.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    blacklist.push(user);

    blockthis();
});
```

Getting this error all the time:

> onclick.js, line 4 
>   in blacklist.push(user) 
>   ReferenceError: blacklist is not defined

link : https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1054941/latest/

Answer (score 2):

A content script and your extension code don't run in the same context - they don't share any variables, so you cannot simply access a variable from your extension in your context. Also, you cannot use SDK modules in a content script. The content script should send a message back to the extension and let it perform all the necessary operations:

```js
self.on("click", function (node) {
    user = node.href.substring(node.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    self.postMessage(user);
    blockthis();
});
```

And in `main.js`:

```js
contextmenu.Item({
    label: "block",
    context: contextmenu.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.min.js"),data.url("onclick.js"),data.url("core.js")],
    onMessage: function(user)
    {
      blacklist.push(user);
    }
});
```

[Further information](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html)

Comment: Thanks for help :), but now i got one more problem.
It's say that "blockthis(); is not defined", which is in "core.js"

function blockthis(){
    for (v in blacklist) {
        str = blacklist[v];

        blocked_div = $('.username_container a[href*=' + str + ']').parent().parent().parent().parent();
        blocked_div.find('img').hide();
    }
}

blockthis();

And look like i cant just write it in main.js, it's use some jquery functions. How i can fix it ?

Comment: I guess that `blockthis()` call has to stay in the content script, only the content script can access the web page. I only moved it because I didn't know what it was doing.

Comment: If you need to use `blacklist` in the content script then you will have to send it there from your `main.js`. But you would probably use `page-mod` to inject this content script - the content script associated with a context menu isn't persistent and IMHO cannot receive messages.

Comment: Look like i'm stuck "blacklist is not defined" again if "blockthis();" is inside a "onclick.js". This is all the code i got, but i cant figure out how to connect it properly. But thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Can you post a link to your builder add-on? It might be simpler for us to look atht ehwole project, be able to run it, etc.

Comment: @canuckistani: I already described the problem in the comment above - `blacklist` needs to be sent to the content script from `main.js`. However, a special-purpose content script created by `context-menu` cannot receive messages, one would need to load a different content script via `page-mod` for that.